# fileupload is not working in php

Tags: php, html

I upload correct jpg file ,but it showing Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed i don't what i did mistake,i want validation the filesize and filetype after moving the image on folder,and chage the filename

```
<?php
$target_dir = "original-photo/";
$original_file=md5($_FILES["file"]["name"].time().rand(10,1000)).'.'.$imageFileType;
 $target_file = $target_dir .$original_file;
 $uploadOk = 1;
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
   if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5000000) {
// echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
header("Location:profilepic.php?filesize=error");
$uploadOk = 0;
 }
 // Allow certain file formats
 if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" &&       $imageFileType != "jpeg"
 && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
 header("Location:profilepic.php?filetype=error");
 //echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
  if ($uploadOk == 0) {
   echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
   // if everything is ok, try to upload file
   } else {
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))        {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
     } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You are telling pathinfo to look for the new file you want to move to after validation, but since the validation isn't done the file doesn't exist at the new location. You need to use the temp path of the `$_FILES` global.

Answer (score 0):

Replace....

```
//Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType!="jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
header("Location:profilepic.php?filetype=error");
//echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
```

With this....

```
$allowTheseImageTypes=array("image/gif", "image/pjpeg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/x-png");
//test the image type here
if (!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $allowTheseImageTypes)){
   header("Location:profilepic.php?filetype=error");
   //echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Allow certain file formats
$arrayTypeAllowed = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/png");
$imageFileType = $_FILES["file"]["type"]
```

change this

```
 if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" &&       $imageFileType != "jpeg"
 && $imageFileType != "gif" )
```

with this

```
if (!in_array($imageFileType,arrayTypeAllowed)) {
     //echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
     $uploadOk = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing md5 for entire file. try below code may be helpful

```
   <?php
$target_dir = "original-photo/";

$image_path = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$target_file = $image_path['filename'].'_'.time().'.'.$image_path['extension']
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the file extension, use

instead

`$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

this:

`$extension = trim(substr(strrchr($filename, "."), 1));`

This is many times faster than using pathinfo() and getting the value from array.

Comment: So I could just upload bitmaps by just changing the extension to .jpg? Great!